# How to efficient create SimpleITK image?

Tags: c++, simpleitk

I have two really long std::vector  `m1` and `m2`. To create two SimpleITK images i currently do this:

```
sitk::PixelIDValueEnum pixelType = sitk::sitkUInt8;
sitk::PixelIDValueEnum pixelTypeFloat = sitk::sitkFloat32;

std::vector<unsigned int> imageSize{d0, d1, l_size};
sitk::Image sitk_m1( imageSize, pixelType );
sitk::Image sitk_m2( imageSize, pixelTypeFloat );

for(unsigned int i=0;i<l_size;i++)
{
    for(unsigned int j=0;j<d1;j++)
    {
        for(unsigned int k=0;k<d0;k++)
        {
             sitk_m1.SetPixelAsUInt8({j,k,i}, m1[d0*d1*i + (j*d1+k)]);
             sitk_m2.SetPixelAsFloat({j,k,i}, m2[d0*d1*i + (j*d1+k)]);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i do this more efficiently? This works, but takes about 10 seconds with approach.

Comment: Did you compile in Release mode?  I have seen cases in Visual Studio where Debug mode took 100 times longer than Release mode to run for the same code and data. What are the dimensions?

Comment: @drescherjm the dimensions are 4000 * 4000 * 1500

Comment: I expect 10 seconds is good for such a large image.

Comment: @drescherjm Sorry, I didn't mention, that 10 Seconds were for 4000*4000*4 elements. 4000*4000*1500 is the image size the app will be used in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SimpleITK's ImageImportFilter.

Here's a simple example that shows how it work:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> imageDims{4, 4000, 4000};

std::vector<unsigned char> m1(4000*4000*4, 0);

sitk::ImportImageFilter importer;

importer.SetSize( imageDims );
importer.SetBufferAsUInt8( m1.data() );
sitk::Image sitk_m1 = importer.Execute();
```

Looking at your code, it looks like you're re-ordering the dimensions in your loop.  My example does not do that.  It simple copies the std::vector data into the Image's pixel buffer.  To swap the image axes, use SimpleITK's FlipImageFilter.